# Is it ok to connect a 10000 μF Capacitor to a lithium-ion battery directly?

Tags: capacitor, lithium-ion, high-current, inrush-current, spark

I have a 24 V lithium-ion battery which will pump as Iᵐᵃˣ 40 A and I need to connect a capacitor directly to the 24 V battery which will be 10000 μF(10 mF).

The usage of it is to keep the system stable if it pulled the entire 40 A.

Is it safe or does it need to be charged in a specific way?

Note: There would be BMS attached to this circuit so I am afraid that the BMS would consider it as short circuit.

Comment: How does the load get switched? Is there any need for battery reversal protection?

Comment: See also: [Energy efficient inrush current limiting](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/521060)

Comment: no it wouldn't need any reverse polarity protection because there would be an xt60 connector for the power input

Comment: I checked the link you have put but it would be an overkill for me to use the time delayed relay unfortunately

Comment: I think it will be okay for the capacitor, not sure about the battery as Imax=40A actually seems like a relatively small battery (lithium batteries put out huge currents) but the connector will make a spark every time you connect it.

Comment: 40 A this is stated by me as it would be connected with an inverter, I want to rely on the internal resistance of the capacitor and battery but can't be sure

Comment: What do you think the cap connected directly parallel to battery will help?

Comment: I am afraid if the load ramped up in a a fraction of seconds so the whole system overloads and get shutdown

Comment: Without series element between cap and battery (L or R) most of current will be drained still from battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not OK.

This is a common problem in traction batteries for vehicles. It is solved through precharge.

In a vehicle, the precharge circuit consists at the minimum of:

- A precharge resistor, to limit the inrush current (R1)
- A contactor (high power relay) across the precharge resistor (K2) to bypass the resistor during normal operation

Additionally, the precharge circuit may have:

- A precharge relay (K1), to keep the load from being powered through the precharge resistor when the system is off
- A contactor in line with the other end of the battery (K3) to isolate the load when the system is off

[image: Precharge circuit]

In the typical precharge circuit, the precharge resistor is on the positive terminal of the battery, though it could just as easily be on the negative terminal.
While you are free to use any designators you wish, the ones in this schematic (R1, K2, K2 and K3) appear to be industry standard, so you are encouraged to use them as well.

Since your battery is low voltage (24 V), you may not require galvanic isolation. In that case, you can skip the precharge relay (K1) and the negative contactor (K3).

---

Consider connecting the capacitor directly and permanently to the string of cells (before the BMS). In that case, use a precharge resistor to charge the capacitor, then connect the capacitor permanently to the string of cells.

Comment: can a transistor be used instead of a relay?

Comment: "can a transistor be used". Yes.

Answer (score 1):

One low tech solution putting most responsibility with the user is to use two connectors, one equipped with about 0.6 Ω series resistance, to be plugged in first, maybe smaller than the main power connector, contact material optimised for high wear resistance rather than low contact resistance.
I didn't have much luck finding connectors with a low number of contacts including more than one 'leading' contact, and most promise mere milliseconds between contact of leading  to regular contacts.

Comment: I thought of relying on battery wires or something too but would NTC solve it, in the link you had put it stated this solution but would it be effective for such thing would it work because we are speaking of milliseconds here if not micro

Comment: To work well, the load would need to be almost constant, and the NTC to get HOT.

Comment: thought of that too, so can I use a pre charge circuit based on a transistor that charges the capacitor slowly? would it be power efficient in normal cases?

Comment: `slowly` takes me back to something to add to the question: How does the load get switched / what voltage profile/timing is acceptable? Time constant of 10 mF\*0.6 Ω is a mere 6 ms.

Comment: it would be 24 VDC as stated above the load would be an inverter(it has a soft starting feature) it will be switched via high current MOSFET, no problem for the timing